# Google Chrome extension to filter posts on Facebook

Tags: chrome, facebook

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can hide all posts in my newsfeed containing some specific URLs. I would provide the list of URLs to ban. I am especially interested in hiding posts linking to parody websites like http://wunderground.ie or http://www.legorafi.fr.

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a extension called [Social Fixer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/social-fixer-for-facebook/ifmhoabcaeehkljcfclfiieohkohdgbb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) which among various other tweaks allows you to filter posts. It can be complicated to setup filters however so a read through the [documentation](http://socialfixer.com/faq.html) is a definite requirement!